# My Mortgage Calculator program on Java cannot produce output

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a simple mortgage calculator program, but it seems like after asking for inputs, the program can't execute output. Would you guys please take a look at my code and let me know where did it go wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

```
package com.ntrinh;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Principle: ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        int principle = (int) scanner1.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Annual Interest: ");
        float interest = (float) scanner1.nextFloat();
        float result_interest = interest/100/12;

        System.out.print("Period (years): ");
        float period = (float) scanner1.nextFloat();
        float result_period = period * 12;

        double mortgage = (double) scanner1.nextDouble();
        double result_mortgage = principle
                * (result_interest * Math.pow(1 + result_interest, result_period))
                / (Math.pow(1 + result_interest, result_period) - 1);

        String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(result_mortgage);
        System.out.println("Mortgage: " + mortgageFormatted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `double mortgage = (double) scanner1.nextDouble();` you don't use it, and it doesn't have a print, so you may forget to input a value. Also remove the cast on nextInt, nextFloat there are useless

Answer (score 1):

You wait for another value at `double mortgage = (double) scanner1.nextDouble();`

Add a print before this line so that user knows that one more value is needed for the calculation.

Once you enter it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the app continues execution.